# Как настроить автодеплой проекта?

Tags: git, git-push, непрерывная-интеграция

Проект написан на JS, код лежит в репозитории. Какое ПО надо поставить на сервере, которое позволит запустить prod сборку при `git push`?
Прикладываю скрин с настроек вебхуков с битбакета чтоб нагляднее было.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скрина мы настраиваем триггер на git push, в поле URL надо указать адрес, который будет дернут, когда триггер сработает. Так вот как мне запустить build.sh на серваке, если доступ к нему открыт только по 80 порту и 22 порт ssh ? Выкладывать наружу php скрипт который будет запускать сборку.... как то не правильно.

Comment: Какая дверь должна быть открыта на сервере, что бы хук сработал?

Comment: На сервере лежит build.sh, запустив который, произойдет клонирование ветки мастер и сборка проекта. На сервере открыты только 80 и 22 порты. При настройке хука, требуется указать адрес, который git будет дергать при git push. Так вот как он его дернет, если build.sh не доступен извне?

Comment: какую команду??